# Apply RTL on all Pages

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to apply RTL on ALL of my pages. 
I have this code and it's working however when i go to another page or refresh, it changes back to LTR. Does anyone know how to apply it on all pages? Because I've only seen answers on how to apply it on just one page.

RTL JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  /** LANGUAGE BUTTONS **/
  $( ".lang-en" ).click(function() {
    if($(document.body).hasClass('rtl')){ $(document.body).removeClass('rtl');} 
  });

  $( ".lang-ar" ).click(function() {
    if(!$(document.body).hasClass('rtl')){ $(document.body).addClass('rtl');} 
  });
});
```

HTML:

```
<ul class="list-inline m-0 p-0">
              <li class="list-inline-item"><button class="lang-en btn-plain p-1 active">English</button></li>
              <li class="list-inline-item"><button class="lang-ar btn-plain p-1">العربية</button></li>
            </ul>
```

Comment: I assume that your classes are correctly applying the relevant change. In this case, you'll want to make use of a `SESSION` or `COOKIE` to store the user's preference between page navigation.

Comment: Local storage is best for you to hold class. https://www.google.com.np/search?dcr=0&source=hp&ei=YpuoWvymKci20AT_6LOIDw&q=localstorage+jquery&oq=localstorage+jquery&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0l3j0i22i10i30k1j0i22i30k1j0i22i10i30k1j0i22i30k1l2j0i22i10i30k1l2.1800.1800.0.2105.2.1.0.0.0.0.232.232.2-1.1.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..1.1.231.0...0.dg08XgyosKk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JavaScript is stateless so in this case you need to take help from localStorage or cookie, try following way:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  /** LANGUAGE BUTTONS **/
  $('body').addClass(localStorage.getItem("lang"));
  $(".lang-en").click(function() {
    localStorage.setItem('lang', 'ltr');
    $('body').removeClass('rtl').addClass(localStorage.getItem("lang"));
  });

  $(".lang-ar").click(function() {
    localStorage.setItem('lang', 'rtl');
    $('body').removeClass('ltr').addClass(localStorage.getItem("lang"));
  });
});
```

Comment: thanks! this worked perfectly :) i had an idea that i needed to use cookies but was not sure how to, this helped a lot.